# How to subtract a value in a vector from the previous number?

Tags: r

```r
vec<-c(  19454,   37954 ,  54954 ,   70954 ,    85954 ,  98954 )
#expected output:
(37954 -19454,54954 -37954,70954 -54954 ,85954 -70954,98954 -85954 )
# i.e: 
18500 17000 16000 15000 13000
```

I'm trying to subtract a value within a vector from the previous value, is there a function that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `diff` to take the difference between adjacent elements

```
diff(vec)
#[1] 18500 17000 16000 15000 13000
```

Or another option is to remove the first and last elements of vector and then do the difference (`-`)

```
vec[-1] - vec[-length(vec)]
#[1] 18500 17000 16000 15000 13000
```

Comment: is there any way to make the diff function not delete a line?

Comment: @RIckHenr It is not clear to me.  I was looking at your expected output and I get the same

Comment: @RIckHenr If you want the result vector to be the same length as the input you might want to add an "NA" e.g. c(NA, vec[-1] - vec[-length(vec)]). - The result will be #[1] NA 18500 17000 16000 15000 13000; and have the same length as your original "vec".